# Annotations on MapView: Coordinates

Tags: objective-c, mkannotation

I have two `NSString`s (address, and key) which contain the coordinates (longitude and latitude) in form of numbers (34,56789...):

```
NSString *key = [allKeys objectAtIndex:i];
NSObject *obj = [DictionaryMap objectForKey:key];

NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", obj];


CLLocationCoordinate2D anyLocation;

anyLocation.latitude = [address doubleValue];

anyLocation.longitude  = [key doubleValue];

MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; annotationPoint2.coordinate = anyLocation;

annotationPoint2.title = @"Event";
annotationPoint2.subtitle = @"Microsoft's headquarters2";
[mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint2];
```

...But I can't understand why it doesn't plot in the same point as the coordinates written. I think this doesn't work:

```
[address doubleValue]
```

So I tried replacing it with:

```
location.latitude = NSNumber/NSString
```

but it gives an error.

UPDATE:

IN VIEW DID LOAD:

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGesture:)];
[self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];

[mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
```

..then...

```
-(void)handleLongPressGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer*)sender {
// This is important if you only want to receive one tap and hold event
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
    [self.mapView removeGestureRecognizer:sender];
}
else
{

    // Here we get the CGPoint for the touch and convert it to latitude and longitude coordinates to display on the map
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord = [self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
    // Then all you have to do is create the annotation and add it to the map

MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init]; annotationPoint.coordinate = locCoord;

    annotationPoint.title = @"Microsoft";
    annotationPoint.subtitle = @"Microsoft's headquarters";
    [mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];

NSString *latitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",locCoord.latitude];


    NSString *longitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", locCoord.longitude];

    NSLog(latitude);
    NSLog(longitude);


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:latitude forKey:@"FolderLatitude"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:longitude forKey:@"FolderLongitude"];
}
}
```

...I then save the coordinates in a JSON file and then read them from the file.

Comment: `NSNumber/NSString` doesn't make any sense in ObjC. What's the error? What did you think would happen? Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish overall? It's not very clear.

Comment: No, I just meant I tried first with an NSNumber (not compatible parameter strong), and then a NSString (same error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I understood: This is the correct way to make it work:

```
NSString *myString = (string initialization here)

float stringFloat = [myString floatValue];

anyLocation.longitude = stringFloat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Print out the values that you are setting for lat/lon. It sounds like these values are not being converted to double properly. If the strings are not in "xxx.xxx" format then they will not convert to doubles properly when you call `doubleValue`.

Comment: lat: 44.840291, lon: 17.841797

Comment: is this how you printed them out? NSLog(@"lat: %@, lon: %@", address, key)

Comment: NSString *latitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f",locCoord.latitude]; ..... NSLog(latitude);

Comment: Oh sorry:  CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:self.mapView];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D locCoord = [self.mapView convertPoint:point toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];                       ...under handleLongPressGesture

Comment: You may need to change the last parameter to whatever view the point is coming from

Comment: How can I do this? The coordinations are standard, I think

Comment: Please update your answer with the all the code for the gesture recognizer, how you are creating it and the action method.